# Cannot save files in Kdenlive snap, why not?

Tags: permissions, filesystem, security, snap, kdenlive

For some reason, Kdenlive (snap version) is not saving files. The program things it is saving, but nothing is actually written to the disk. I've enabled removable drive access permissions, but that hasn't changed anything.

It won't even save anything in the `~/Snap/kdenlive` folder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same problem.
`kdenlive` (snap version) does not save file in `.kdenlive` format; but the project is saved in a other way.
If you go to the `kdenlive` folder and show the hidden data, you can see file like this `.xdp_321.MAXUN0`, 321 is the file name you have saved before.

Open this file with `kdenlive`, then you will get your saved project back.

Answer (score 0):

With the snap version of Kdenlive, you can only save files under your home folder by default. You also cannot save to symbolic links pointing to places outside of your home folder. So make sure you are trying to save to an allowed location.

To extend the possibility to write to removable drives, find Kdenlive in the software center, go into the page of the version you installed and click the Permissions button. Check "Read/write on removable storage devices". That confinement is not enabled by default.

Comment: It's not saving *anything*, not even in the home folder. I do have removable storage permissions enabled (I mentioned this in the question).

Answer (score 0):

If your home folder is using a symbolic link to another larger hard drive, many snap packages will not work properly.

Just use the Appimage version from https://kdenlive.org/en/download/

It will solve you a lot of problems related to snap and write permissions in such situations.

Answer (score 0):

The solution [here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=265&t=154096) seemed to work for me. Just add .kdenlive as the file extension when saving.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1219278)

Comment: @NonnyMoose I did include the solution. Add .kdenlive as the file extension. It’s a really easy fix. Then I linked the source.

Answer (score 0):

Have been searching quite a while for a workable solutions, in the end what seemed to work was uninstalling all existing versions, then upgrading from v18 ubuntu to v20, then reinstalling kdenlive from PPA repo (option 2 here: https://linuxhint.com/install_kdenlive_ubuntu/). After that could save to file. Also the appimage version from here worked now: https://kdenlive.org/en/download/
In other words: doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu 18.

Comment: Hi René le Belge, this answer, while useful - is not related to the question's specifics: which refer to saving Kdenlive files with the snap version. Fortunately, this has been addressed since this question was posted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).